# App Feed Swipe Error

Tags: bug, ios-app

When viewing the feed, swiping down **sometimes** does not work, it shows the Refreshing... animation and then stays like that.

Selecting the Menu button then Feed still works but that's cumbersome.

I'm on iOS 10.3 Public Beta 2

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPhone 6 Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.3 (Build 14E5239e)

Comment: No repro. Version 1.6.3.6, iPhone 6S, iOS 10.2

Comment: No repro. v1.6.3.6/1.6.4 iPhone 6S 10.2.1

Comment: Does happen to me on iOS 10.1 occasionally. Killing the app usually resolves the problem (double-tap home, then swipe the app out)